# Jenkins job getting failed on getpass.py file raise EOF error

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, eoferror

Jenkins Pipeline job is getting failed with these logs in the deployment stage of my code:

```
  Logs:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 642, in prompt_for_password
    new_password = _password_prompt(password_prompt, stream)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 614, in _password_prompt
    return getpass.getpass(prompt.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), stream)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/getpass.py", line 83, in unix_getpass
    passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/getpass.py", line 118, in fallback_getpass
    return _raw_input(prompt, stream)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/getpass.py", line 135, in _raw_input
    raise EOFError
EOFError
[Pipeline] load
```

Please help in resolving the error at the earliest, what is the reason behind EOF error.